# How to add path parameter in elasticsearch Java bulk Api

Tags: elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I'm using Java bulk Api,Elasticsearch 6.6.2, and expect to POST bulk request as
`POST /<index>/_bulk`,
but i got `POST /_bulk` instead (see packet captured below).

I know these 2 POST methods are the same, but there're a proxy between my app and ES, the path parameter is for the proxy for some reasons(I don't know why).

so, I wonder how to set the [path parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk-api-path-params) in Java ,so that request can be sent in `POST /<index>/_bulk` format.

Here's the code

```
        RestHighLevelClient client;
        /* some client init code ....*/
        ...
        String INDEX = "api_track";
        String DOC_TYPE = "_doc";

        BulkProcessor.Builder builder = BulkProcessor.builder(
                (request, bulkListener) ->
                        client.bulkAsync(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT, bulkListener),
                listener);
        builder.setBulkActions(500);
        builder.setBulkSize(new ByteSizeValue(1L, ByteSizeUnit.MB));
        builder.setConcurrentRequests(0);
        builder.setFlushInterval(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(5L));
        builder.setBackoffPolicy(BackoffPolicy
                .constantBackoff(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(1L), 3));
        builder.setGlobalIndex(INDEX);
        builder.setGlobalType(DOC_TYPE);
        bulkProcessor = builder.build();

        IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest().index(INDEX).type(DOC_TYPE).source(maps);
        bulkProcessor.add(request);
```

and the packet captured:

```
    0x0000:  0200 0000 4500 0277 0000 4000 4006 12c9  ....E..w..@.@...
    0x0010:  1e27 dee3 0ba3 1d0b e142 23f0 85d1 ad67  .'.......B#....g
    0x0020:  1540 31d3 8018 0801 3eb0 0000 0101 080a  .@1.....>.......
    0x0030:  1500 c5e6 b6ba 7ff0 504f 5354 202f 5f62  ........POST./_b   <-- POST format here
    0x0040:  756c 6b3f 7469 6d65 6f75 743d 316d 2048  ulk?timeout=1m.H
    0x0050:  5454 502f 312e 310d 0a43 6f6e 7465 6e74  TTP/1.1..Content
    0x0060:  2d4c 656e 6774 683a 2033 3335 0d0a 436f  -Length:.335..Co
    0x0070:  6e74 656e 742d 5479 7065 3a20 6170 706c  ntent-Type:.appl
    0x0080:  6963 6174 696f 6e2f 6a73 6f6e 0d0a 486f  ication/json..Ho
    0x0090:  7374 3a20 7365 6172 6368 2e61 6c69 7061  st:.search.alipa
    0x00a0:  792e 6e65 743a 3932 3030 0d0a 436f 6e6e  y.net:9200..Conn
    0x00b0:  6563 7469 6f6e 3a20 4b65 6570 2d41 6c69  ection:.Keep-Ali
    0x00c0:  7665 0d0a 5573 6572 2d41 6765 6e74 3a20  ve..User-Agent:.
    0x00d0:  4170 6163 6865 2d48 7474 7041 7379 6e63  Apache-HttpAsync
    0x00e0:  436c 6965 6e74 2f34 2e31 2e34 2028 4a61  Client/4.1.4.(Ja
    0x00f0:  7661 2f31 2e38 2e30 5f31 3531 290d 0a41  va/1.8.0_151)..A
    0x0100:  7574 686f 7269 7a61 7469 6f6e 3a20 4261  uthorization:.Ba
    0x0110:  7369 6320 6247 6c75 6132 4d36 527a 4e61  sic.bGlua2M6RzNa
    0x0120:  5954 4e4e 5755 593d 0d0a 0d0a 7b22 696e  YTNNWUY=....{"in
    0x0130:  6465 7822 3a7b 225f 696e 6465 7822 3a22  dex":{"_index":"
    0x0140:  6170 695f 7472 6163 6b22 2c22 5f74 7970  api_track","_typ
    0x0150:  6522 3a22 5f64 6f63 227d 7d0a 7b22 6372  e":"_doc"}}.{"cr
    0x0160:  6561 7465 6441 7422 3a22 3230 3230 2d30  eatedAt":"2020-0
    0x0170:  322d 3132 5430 383a 3438 3a34 332e 3333  2-12T08:48:43.33
    0x0180:  3822 2c22 686f 7374 4164 6472 223a 2231  8","hostAddr":"1
    0x0190:  3237 2e30 2e30 2e31 222c 2274 656e 616e  27.0.0.1","tenan
    0x01a0:  7449 6422 3a6e 756c 6c2c 2273 6572 7665  tId":null,"serve
    0x01b0:  724e 616d 6522 3a6e 756c 6c2c 2270 6172  rName":null,"par
    0x01c0:  616d 7322 3a22 2670 7269 7661 7465 5f74  ams":"&private_t
    0x01d0:  6f6b 656e 3d2a 2a2a 266f 7264 6572 5f62  oken=***&order_b
    0x01e0:  793d 7369 7a65 222c 2275 7365 724e 616d  y=size","userNam
    0x01f0:  6522 3a22 6d79 7363 6d22 2c22 7573 6572  e":"myscm","user
    0x0200:  4964 223a 3330 3034 2c22 7061 7468 6e61  Id":3004,"pathna
    0x0210:  6d65 223a 222f 6170 692f 7634 2f70 726f  me":"/api/v4/pro
    0x0220:  6a65 6374 732f 3339 3235 352f 6c61 6e67  jects/39255/lang
    0x0230:  7561 6765 7322 2c22 7265 6d6f 7465 4164  uages","remoteAd
    0x0240:  6472 223a 2233 302e 3339 2e32 3232 2e32  dr":"30.39.222.2
    0x0250:  3237 222c 2275 7064 6174 6564 4174 223a  27","updatedAt":
    0x0260:  2232 3032 302d 3032 2d31 3254 3038 3a34  "2020-02-12T08:4
    0x0270:  383a 3433 2e33 3338 227d 0a              8:43.338"}.
```

Comment: Please update your question with the value/the initialization of the variable INDEX

Comment: the value of INDEX is not important,  can be any value. In this example, equals 'api_track'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by `client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest(new Request(method, endpoint))`, fill INDEX into parameter of `method`.